# Render Table jQuery weird load order

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm pulling data from a JSON file with jQuery.

I am then trying to create a table with that data. It works perfectly however my second piece of code is rendering a HighCharts graph which uses the latter table to create a graph.

Here is what I'm using to render the table (it's not pretty):

```
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
       var items = [];

       $('.contn').append("<table id='datatable'>");                


       $('.contn').append("<thead><tr><th></th> <th>Take</th> <th>Accrue</th></tr></thead><tbody>");
       $.each(data.wlc_lieu_time, function(key, val) {

            $('.contn').append("<tr><th>" + val.Month + "</th><td>"+ val.Take + "</td><td>" + val.Accrue + "</td></tr>"); 
        })
         $('.contn').append("</tbody></table>");

    });
```

Then I render the graph:

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
                    table: document.getElementById('datatable')
                },
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
                });
```

Firstly, the chart doesn't pick up on the table which I'm presuming is a load order. 
How can I make sure that the table is created before the chart looks for the table?

Here is the official documentation for the HighCharts w/ pulling data from a table to generate a graph can be found [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/)

Comment: Have you tried calling the chart code in the success callback of the getJSON function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe is because you're using ajax to get the data, so the highcharts method is called before the data.json is fully loaded. You should wait until the getJson is complete before trying to render the chart.

Comment: I'm just rebuilding the page on my home computer now (I did this at work), I'll get back to you when I'm done.

Comment: Indeed, just create chart inside getJSON callback, after table was rendered.